# Removing Animations in dopesheet action editor

Tags: dopesheet

I opened up the dopesheet, and then the action editor. I pressed f, then 2, experimenting with it. But doing that made clones of the animation. How do I delete them?[image: See Idle.005? That's the fifth clone I accidentally made.]

Comment: Did you see the answer provided?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the animations with the 'X' button. The active ones or the ones with the 'F' button enabled will be saved after reloading your saved .blend file.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is late but I found it so hard to find the answer anywhere else.

As shown in Tak's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77552/96415), you need to click the "X" button, HOWEVER you need to hold the shift key while pressing this "X".

If it works, in the dropdown containing your animations in the dope sheet, the animation you want to delete should have a "0" next to it.

From there, you just need to save your file, exit blender, then reopen the file and it should be gone.

Comment: Hi, welcome! You could perhaps add at least one screenshot (use the question editor image tool) to clarify what has to be done, where

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting it as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Tried that, but they're still there.

Comment: @Alpex could you provide your .blend file to be able to help